# Mail without SMTP port in Laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp, phpmailer

I am new to `laravel` and `PHP` and I have a `godaddy` shared hosting which does not provide `SMTP` port.

How do I send the mail without that port?

My mail controller is:

```
public function mail1(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [

    ]);
    $data = array(
        'email' => $request->email,
        'typeOfService'=>$request->typeOfService,
        'name'=>$request->name,
        'mobile'=>$request->mobile,
    );
    Mail::send('email.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->from('nikhil@domain.co');
        $message->subject('Inquiry from Domain');
        $message->to('selva@domain.in');
    });
```

My .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.zoho.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=nikhil@domain.co
MAIL_PASSWORD=my***password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL
```

Hope someone would answer this.

Comment: In your config, `MAIL_DRIVER` value should be `smtp`.

Comment: GoDaddy does block outbound SMTP, but they provide their own mail server you can send through, and I think their shared hosting routes messages through it from localhost by default, so you should be able to send using the `mail` transport. Read their docs.

Comment: @Synchro I'll check that thanks anyway

Comment: Thank a lot @Synchro the mistake i did was using another domain's mail id rather than that specific website.

Comment: your answer helped me a lot in this process